# Custom FormArray with Checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-forms, formarray

I'm trying to show a list of the interests as checkboxes and check if they are selected or not. I'm having some troubles with the formArray and trying to get everything set up. The goal is to loop over all the interests in the interests array and show each of them as a checkbox. That way I can provide validation for it going forward. Thank you to anyone who replies, thank you!
[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div *ngFor="let item of getControls(); let i = index">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          [formControl]="item"
          [id]="i"
          (change)="checkBoxClicked(item, i)"
        />
        {{ item.value }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

interests = [
'Music',
'Technology',
'Sports',
'Art',
'Fashion',
'Gaming',
'Education',
'Business',
];

selectedInterests = [];

createForm() {
this.form = new FormGroup({
  projectName: new FormControl(null, {
    validators: [Validators.required],
  }),
  description: new FormControl(null, {
    validators: [Validators.required],
  }),
  interestsArray: new FormArray([]),
});

this.interests.forEach((item) => {
  const interest = this.form.controls.interestsArray as FormArray;
  const interestFormControl = new FormControl(false);
  interest.push(interestFormControl);
});
console.log(this.form);


getControls() {
return (this.form.get('interestsArray') as FormArray).controls;
}

checkBoxClicked(name, index) {
// console.log(document.getElementById(name.value.split('-')[0]));
this.selectedInterests.push(name);
console.log(name);
console.log(this.selectedInterests);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
export class AppComponent {
  public form: FormGroup;
  public selectedInterests = [];
  public interests = [ 'Music','Technology','Sports','Art','Fashion','Gaming','Education','Business'];

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
      this.selectedInterests = Object.entries(x.interestsArray)
        .filter(([, value]) => value)
        .map(([key]) => key);
        
      console.log(this.selectedInterests)
    });
  }

  public createForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      projectName: [null, Validators.required],
      description: [null, Validators.required],
      interestsArray: this.fb.group(
        this.interests.reduce((x, y) => ({ ...x, [y]: [false] }), {})
      )
    });
  }
}
```

And in your templates:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <form formGroupName="interestsArray"
          *ngFor="let item of interests">
          <input type="checkbox"
            [formControlName]="item"
            [id]="item"/>
          {{ item }}
        </form>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```